# Analytically solving (finding a maxima) a system of equations involving PolyLog functions (Fermi-Dirac Integrals)

Tags: systems-of-equations, improper-integrals, polylogarithm

I have the following system of equations involving PolyLog functions (Fermi Dirac Integrals) where $d,t\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $d,t >0$ such that

$$
J = J_0 \cdot \left[F_{\frac{d-1}{t}}\left(\eta\right)-F_{\frac{d-1}{t}}\left(\eta-v_d\right)\right]\\
n = n_0 \cdot\left[F_{\frac{d-t}{t}}\left(\eta\right)+F_{\frac{d-t}{t}}\left(\eta-v_d\right)\right]
$$
Where we denote the Fermi-Dirac integral of order $j$ as $F_{j}\left(\eta\right)= \frac{1}{\Gamma\left(j+1\right)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{j}}{1+e^{u-\eta}}\,\mathrm{d}u$. Here $J_0,n_0$ and $v_d$ are constants. Only variable in the above system of equations is $\eta$. I want to get an analytical understanding of how $J/n$ varies with $n$.

I can take two limits of the Fermi-Dirac integral. (Section 4 on Asymptotic Expansions of https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.0116.pdf)

1. $\eta \gg 0$, in which we can approximate $ F_{j}({\eta})\approx \frac{\eta^{j+1}}{\Gamma(j+2)}$, if we use this we get $J = Constant \times v_d\times n^{\frac{d-1}{d}}$. So clearly $J/n = Constant \times v_d\times n^{-\frac{1}{d}}$.
2. $\eta \ll 0$, in which we can approximate $ F_{j}({\eta})\approx e^{\eta}$, if we use this we get $J/n = Constant\times \tanh\left({v_d/2}\right)$.

So, I can see how the function behaves in the two limits, but what I really want to capture is how $J/n$ behaves for all $\eta$ (or $n$). I solved the two equations numerically for different values of $d,t$ and I find that there is always a maxima in $J/n$ as a function of $n$. If I can in some way capture that analytically, that there would be one maxima and approximately at what value of $n$ that maxima would occur, it would be highly useful for me.

Comment: Are $d$ and $t$ linked ? Because, if $d = t= \nu_d = 1$, one can compute an explicit solution and there is no maximum.

Comment: No they are independent, but in your case, I guess the maxima is always near $n \to 0$. Only in $t=1$ case does the maxima occur near $n \to 0$. In all other cases maxima occurs somewhere in middle. Is there any way to show it?

Comment: As a beginning, the case $d=t$, $t>1$ may be more tractable because the denominator, $n$ is explicit.

Comment: Thanks for your help, were you able to deduce anything from the numerical solutions?

Comment: I think we can just study the sign of the derivative $J/n$ according to $\eta$ and prove (with conditions on $d$, $t$, $\nu$) that it is $>0$ when $\eta < 0$ (using the exponential behavior of $F_j$ in $\eta \to -\infty$). Then, I think it is less difficult to prove that it becomes $ < 0$ (and maybe get informations on the localization of this maximum) and stay $< 0$ when $\eta > \simeq 0$. The maximum seems to be attained when $\eta \leq \simeq \nu_d$ and it can simplify the study.

Comment: @jvc Thanks for the insight, did you write the solution down somewhere? It would be of great help to me personally and to the community if you can post your solution (even if it is incomplete) as an answer.